# preact signals, how to do rendering optimization on non-primitive values

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, preact

in the README of preact signals, it introduces a rendering optimizations
https://github.com/preactjs/signals/blob/main/packages/preact/README.md#rendering-optimizations

> simply pass the signal directly instead of accessing the .value property.

but if I create an array signal, like a todo list

```js
const todos = signal([
  { text: "Buy groceries" },
  { text: "Walk the dog" },
]);
```

how do I do the rendering optimization on it?

or does it mean the optimization is only for simple primitive values like strings or numbers?

Comment: The rendering optimization is to bind your signal value to a `Text` node, as described in that link. How would you expect an array of objects to be represented as a text node?